# pytest with Flask can't locate module

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I am learning **Flask** following this tutorial https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/#user-s-guide but, when I try to run `pytest`, I get this error:

```
(FlaskVenv) MacBook-Pro-de-Hugo:FlaskProject hugovillalobos$ pytest
ImportError while loading conftest '/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/FlaskProject/tests/conftest.py'.
tests/conftest.py:4: in <module>
    from Flaskr import create_app
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Flaskr'
```

This is the module that raises the error (`conftest.py`):

```
import os
import tempfile
import pytest
from Flaskr import create_app
from Flaskr.db import get_db, init_db

with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data.sql'), 'rb') as f:
    _data_sql = f.read().decode('utf8')

@pytest.fixture
def app():
    db_fd, db_path = tempfile.mkstemp()

    app = create_app({
        'TESTING': True,
        'DATABASE': db_path,
    })

    with app.app_context():
        init_db()
        get_db().executescript(_data_sql)

    yield app

    os.close(db_fd)
    os.unlink(db_path)

@pytest.fixture
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()

@pytest.fixture
def runner(app):
    return app.test_cli_runner()
```

This is the code for such module as shown in the tutorial (the only difference is that my module is capitalized):

[image]

I though it might be a problem with the location of my files, but I am mapping the tutorial project layout correctly:

[image]

I don't know what I am missing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You might need to run pytest as a module in python (which adds the current directory to sys.path). I remember having a similar situation and this resolved it for me:

```
python -m pytest -vv
```

---

Source: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#calling-pytest-through-python-m-pytest

You can invoke testing through the Python interpreter from the command line:

python -m pytest [...]
This is almost equivalent to invoking the command line script pytest [...] directly, except that calling via python will also add the current directory to sys.path.

Comment: Yes!!! it works. Thank you

Comment: @HuLuViCa consider upvoting the answer if it helped you. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Yo got it, sr. Any way, I liked @Aneuway solution because it works without any modification to my project. I think he should add his answer to the question you reference. Some people might find it useful.

Comment: No, I meant to upvote @Aneuway's answer :-)

Comment: You are so right :)